# use a specific ip address for outgoing request in java

Tags: java, httprequest

I try to do a http request from my server and want to use different ip addresses (do one request with one IP and another with another IP). I read that it should work with the http client of apache. This is the code i use:

```
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom();
Builder configBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
configBuilder.setLocalAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {85,2,(byte) 246,4}));
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(configBuilder.build()).build();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://xy.com/");
CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
//do something with the response
response1.close();
```

resulting in the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
```

at the line "CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);"

What am I doing wrong? (It don't has to be done with apache, it just needs to be java. Best would be Play Framework because I normally do my request with that but I just want it to work, anything else is secondary)

Thanks

Comment: I think this error means that it cannot reach a port on the IP you assigned. When you try your local IP (`{127, 0, 0, 1}`) does that work?

Comment: the upcomming error is then:
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect

Comment: Do you see that it automatically "pings" to port 80 of the website? You could try changing that to your settings and try it out. You could also use HttpPost if you need to use that.

Comment: how can I see if it pings? btw I'm not sure if you understand me correct, the request should come from my server to en external webpage (normal http get request). It also works fine if I don't do the "setLocalAddress()" but the used outgoing IP is then just the normal IP and that's not my intention. (perhaps it's the wrong way to change it with "setLocalAddress", I don't know?!). I just want to do a request using a different IP.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. But since this error is a bit tricky (and I think that that's the reason that you still didn't have an answer in 2 hours on StackOverflow) I wanted to try out some things. Maybe someone else will help you out here, tomorrow I can try and test the code myself.

Comment: Ok thanks in advance :) Yeah I know I already tried hours before I posted :(